# Bind Data to Lightning Design System in a Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, standardcontroller, html5

How can I bind data to controls built in the lightning design system **within visualforce**.  It seems that it's more HTML/CSS based vs apex:control based.

*Changing my question to refine and make more relevant*

I need to send multiple parameters to a controller from Javascript

here is my **actionFunction** binding the controller call to the javascript and the params I'd like to send.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="sendValue">
        <apex:param value="" name="chk" assignTo="{!activity__c.Location_is_approximate__c}"/>
        <apex:param value="" name="lat" assignTo="{!activity__c.GeoCode__Latitude__s}"/>
        <apex:param value="" name="long" assignTo="{!activity__c.GeoCode__Longitude__s}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

Here is the **javascript** that is bound to it

```
function sendData()
{
    var chkVal = document.getElementById('chk');
    //alert(v.checked);
    sendValue(v.checked, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    return false;
}
```

Here is the **controller** that is receiving it

```
public Activity__C act {get; set;}
    public User owner {get; set;}
    public boolean hasLocation; 

    public QuickCreateActivityController(){
       act = new Activity__c();
       owner = new user();
       hasLocation = false;

    }

    public void save() {  

        system.debug(act.Location_is_approximate__c);
        checkForWorkday();     
        insert act;

    }
```

----------------WHAT I ENDED UP DOING USING THE SUGGESTIONS BELOW----------

**action function and button**

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="sendValue" reRender="">
        <apex:param value="" name="param1" assignTo="{!hasLocation}"/>
        <apex:param value="" name="param2" assignTo="{!geoLat}"/>
        <apex:param value="" name="param3" assignTo="{!geoLong}"/> 
    </apex:actionFunction>

<button id="btnSave" class="slds-button--neutral slds-text-heading--medium slds-m-vertical--medium" style="width:100%;" onclick="buttonClick(); return false;">Log my location</button>
```

**Javascript method**

```
function buttonClick(){
   sendValue(chkVal.checked, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public boolean hasLocation {get; set;} 
public double geoLat {get; set;}
public double geoLong {get; set;}

public QuickCreateActivityController(){
   act = new Activity__c();
   owner = new user();   
   hasLocation = false;
   geoLat = 0.0;
   geoLong = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: In multiple field you need to get all fields using `javascript` and then pass them using `apex:param`

Comment: Is this passed in a single param statement or multiple?

Comment: I changed things up to make things more clear.  I took your advice about using params, now I just need to send multiple and have the controller accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to directly bind the field you can use lightning tags

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="expname" label=" Account  Name" value="{!v. account.Name}" required="true"/>
```

here account will be passes as an attribute.

to bind a controller method first you need to call javascript method

```
<ui:button label=”Create Account” press=”{!c.clickCreateRecord}”/>
```

and in javascript controller

```
// Load expenses from Salesforce

clickCreateRecord: function(component, event, helper) {



// Create the action

var action = component.get("c.getaccount");

// Add callback behavior for when response is received

action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

var state = response.getState();

if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {

component.set("v.account", response.getReturnValue());

}

else {

console.log("Failed with state: " + state);

}

});

// Send action off to be executed

$A.enqueueAction(action);

},
```

using these method you can call apex controller. and use @Auraenabled  in controller method and they should be static

```
@AuraEnabled

public static List<account > getaccount()
```

[Reference](https://newstechnologystuff.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/lightning-in-salesforce-part-3/)

**Update** As this a Visualforce page so things are easy here. To display and take user input you can use html tag as you are already using.

And to pass data to controller  just get all these value in controller and pass them using `actionfunction param attribute`

```
<script>
    function sendData()
    {
       var v  = document.getElementById('text-input-01');
       actfun(v);
     }
</script>
<apex:actionfunction action="{!method}" name="actfun" rerender="frm">
      <apex:param value="" name="param" assignTo="contvariable" />
</apex:actionfunction>
```

or you can use remoting here as well.

Comment: shoot!  I should have been more clear.  This is the SLDS design system applied to a visualforce page not a lightning component

Comment: I updated the questions to make that more clear

Comment: @tjcinnamon check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding how this works?  So starting with simple binding the data:  how is 'text-input-01' related to {!account.name}?  If a user was to use this as an edit and create page, presumably data would need to be populated to text-input-01 on open

Comment: @tjcinnamon to display existing data. you can do something like `<input id="text-input-01" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text"  value="{!acc.name}/>` and then you can get the data in javascript and send it to controller to updated data.

Comment: `<!-- works --> 
   <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>                      
      <apex:inputField value="{!contact.lastname}"/>
        
        <!-- does not work-->
      <input id="lastname" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" value="{!contact.lastname}"/>  
      <input id="accountName" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" value="{!contact.account}"/>`

Comment: The upper vForce section works but the lower SLDS does not.  It loads it but will not save

Comment: @tjcinnamon how are you saving it? use actionfunction and pass the parameter

Comment: how would this work with multiple parameters?   I switched to using the contact standard controller for example.  How would I be able to do this

Comment: `<apex:page standardController="contact">
 <apex:form>
   <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>                      
       <apex:inputField value="{!contact.lastname}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!contact.firstname}"/>
     <apex:inputField  value="{!contact.Account}"/>  
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>`

Comment: Perhaps, another option is to use the SLDS with the standard <apex:inputXXXX> control but the CSS doesn't stick

Comment: You can use inputtext with standardstylesheet set to false.